# Moving text on OneNote for iPad

Tags: ipad, applications

I'd like to move text boxes on the official OneNote iPad app, but can't figure out how to do so.

I've tried tapping and dragging, and double-tapping and dragging, but both only scroll the page.

[image: OneNote screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Apple.Stackexchange. Could you add a screenshot please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a regular user of the current OneNote iPad app.  Your only option for moving the text boxes is to use the iOS method for selecting, cutting and pasting.  There is not currently a way to grab text box handle and move the entire box like you can with the desktop app.

After you select and cut your text, tap into the area of the page you wish to move the box and then tap and hold and paste.

FWIW, the rumor mill says that Microsoft will release a full-on touch compatible version of the office suite, including OneNote for the iPad very soon.  Hopefully that version will support more of the features of the desktop app like moving the text boxes.

Happy computing.

Comment: Here is a video demonstration:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c5IWhwY6bMU

Answer (score -2):

You can use onenote online to move and size text boxes
then switch back to app to further edit

Answer (score -2):

I use a program called [Outline+](http://outline.ws/).
It will let you move and size just like using the program on a desktop.
It will also sync with your OneDrive files.
It would be nice if Microsoft could add this.